# Swift - SpriteKit - Update SKAction.waitForDuration while running forever

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, action, skaction

I am trying to update the waitForDuration action in a sequence that is running forever.

```
 override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    //code
    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(runSeq()))
}

func runSeq() -> SKAction{
    var difficulty: CGFloat = 0.75

    let updateAction = SKAction.runBlock({
        self.runCount++
        self.runCount %= 4
        println(self.runCount)
        if self.runCount == 0 {
            difficulty -= 0.1
        }

        if self.children.count > 51{
            println("You loose")
        }else{
            self.scoreLabel.text = String(format: "Score: %i", self.score)
        }
    })

    let createAntAction = SKAction.runBlock({self.createAnt()})

    var wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(difficulty))

    let seq = SKAction.sequence([createAntAction, wait, updateAction])

    return seq
}
```

`difficulty` is the value that I want, and every 4 loops I want it to decrease by a certain amount. Currently, the starting value remains the same, and doesn't change, even though I am changing the `difficulty` value, and recalling the sequence of actions every time.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because wait is already established as .75, and nothing is changing that.  SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(difficulty)) is not looking for a reference to difficulty, only a value, so you need to rethink how you want to code this.